# How to change font size for annotations in dygraphs?

Tags: javascript, css, dygraphs

Take a look at the this example, from [Dygraph setAnnotations with repeated x values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44007718/dygraph-setannotations-with-repeated-x-values) :

http://jsfiddle.net/wn43LLv7/1/

Note that there they tried to use a CSS class:

```
.dygraph-annotation
{
    font-size: 14;
...
```

... which tries to change the font size. However, changing the font size and running the snippet makes no difference whatsoever.

Also, in http://dygraphs.com/annotations.html, it says:

> cssClass  CSS class to use for styling the annotation

... so I made another jsfiddle to test if that can change font size:

http://jsfiddle.net/u7shmody/1/

... and no, it cannot.

Which is probably not a big surprise, because if I look at the annotation in Firefox Inspect Object, I have:

```
<div style="font-size: 14px; left: 217.5px; top: 79.1111px; width: 16px; height: 16px; color: rgb(64, 0, 128); border-color: rgb(64, 0, 128);" class="dygraph-annotation dygraphDefaultAnnotation dygraph-default-annotation myAnnot" title="undefined">A</div>
```

... so, font-size is specified inline in the `style` attribute of the div element, which as far as I know, takes the highest priority in CSS, and no class could otherwise override it (either if we override the library ones like `.dygraph-annotation`, or if we try add our own custom class via `cssClass`).

So, how can one change font size of the annotation in dygraphs? Maybe there is some callback, which can be overriden, so `font-size` can be injected in the element inline style attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

dygraphs 1 only used inline styles. dygraphs 2 moved towards storing its styles in a CSS file (`dygraph.css`) which makes them much easier to override. But this one [got missed](https://github.com/danvk/dygraphs/blob/e9155b2c442bf69396d5a456c885f938d38d35da/src/plugins/annotations.js#L90) for reasons that are lost to time. If there's ever a dygraphs 3, it will probably fix this.

In the meantime, you'll have to use `!important` to override the font size with CSS.

You can also override this in JavaScript, if you prefer. The size of tooltips is determined by the [`axisLabelFontSize`](http://dygraphs.com/options.html#axisLabelFontSize) property. So to change it, you can adjust that property:

```js
new Dygraph(div, data, { axisLabelFontSize: 28 });
```

Of course, this will make the labels on your axes a really big font! To make them more normal, you can adjust them back:

```js
new Dygraph(div, data, {
  axisLabelFontSize: 28,
  axes: {
    x: { axisLabelFontSize: 14 },
    y: { axisLabelFontSize: 14 },
  }
});
```

Definitely a hack, but it might just work!

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @danvk - much appreciated!